# textview only display capital letters

Tags: android

I have a button which when clicked jumbles a word and puts the word into a textview.

I want the textview to only display capital letters.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you mean you want the TextView to capitalize everything that is put into it, then you can set the capitalize XML attribute on the TextView.

If you mean you only want capital letters to show up ex:

"Hi There!" --> "HT"

Then you need a little bit of Java code (from memory, untested):

```
private static String removeLowercase(String input)
{
   if(input == null)
     return null;

   String retVal = "";

   for(int i=0; i < input.length(); i++)
   {
        char c = input.charAt(i);

        if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
            retVal += c;
   }

   return retVal;
}
```

You can then set the text in the TextView:

```
myTV.setText(removeLowercase("SomeInput"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but this doesn't seem to work when I add it to the jumbled word function like this jumble.setText((removeLowercase(wordJ.toString())));, Would it be easier to make the edittext have only capital letters?

Comment: Dont worry, I managed to do this by using android:inputType="textCapCharacters". But your code helped somehow to remove the [] from the jumbled word. Thanks:)

Answer (score 8):

Use android:textAllCaps:true  it will work like a charm

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
   android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />
```

In Java code use

```
   text.toUpperCase()
```

Answer (score 2):

This will convert the text to all uppercase

```
text.toUpperCase()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not defined for the ArrayList<Character>. At the moment it is set as jumble.setText(wordJ.toString()); .